# Run command located at C:\ from folder in another drive

Tags: windows-7, command-line

I want to run the following command:

```
C:\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\pyuic4.bat -x gui.ui -o gui.py
```

From a folder located in `R:\`, that folder contains the file `gui.ui` and the command is suposed to create the file `gui.py` into `R:\`

When I run the command from R:\ in the windows console, it seems to be unable to find the command:

> The system cannot find the path specified.

What can I do?

Comment: It should work as expected, so the only reason it doesn't work is because there's some kind of typo. Make sure the file at C: exists, and also make sure that the .bat file is not generating the error. You can try `r:gui.ui` and `r:gui.py` as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is likely within the batch file you're running, as your command looks correct assuming that file does actually exist.

The chances are, it'll be running using `relative` paths instead of `absolute` paths within your batch. For example, it will contain something along the lines of:

```
executable.exe
```

instead of

```
C:\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\executable.exe
```

You will need to change the paths in your batch file to absolute paths instead, or it will be trying to find them within R:\ - of course, this may cause unexpected results, so you may need to test this carefully.

Comment: The problem was indeed into the .bat file

Comment: If you want to avoid hardcoding paths in the .bat itself, `%~dp0` gives you the path of the batch file being executed.

Comment: @MarcksThomas That's very useful, I didn't know this, thank you for the information!